# i am writing the code by using for loop but the loop is not working

Tags: postgresql

i am writing the code for the v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id   should be check they have parent_id or not if they have parent_id they have to check that they have any parent_id if they not have the parent_id then the id should be go to update condition.Below the example the main_bug_id = 1 should be go to update condition
main_bug_id   parent_id
1
2                1
3                2

here the v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id  = 6270 and paren_id(v_parent_agent_assignment_id) =6240 and the parent_task_id = 8021(which one have to update)
for this v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id have to search that have any parent_id have or not
if they have the parent_id (parent_id have one task_id)then have to update the task which are have the parent_task_id..the loop is not going to elseif condition

```
                 FOR t_row in(select * from project.pm_task_run_agent_assignments 
               where task_run_agent_assignment_id = v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id)
               LOOP
            
            if(t_row.parent_agent_assignment_id is not null) then
                v_parent_agent_assignment_id = 
              (select parent_agent_assignment_id from project.pm_task_run_agent_assignments 
               where task_run_agent_assignment_id = v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id );
                       if(v_parent_agent_assignment_id is not null)then
                            v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id = v_parent_agent_assignment_id;
                       elsif(v_parent_agent_assignment_id is null) then
                        update project.nt_task
                        set status='Reopen'
                        where key_val_id = v_parent_agent_assignment_id and task_type_id = 1;
                        else
                         v_taskrun_agent_assignment_id = 0;
                       end if;
               elsif (t_row.parent_agent_assignment_id is null) then
                update project.nt_task
                set status='Reopen'
                where key_val_id = v_parent_agent_assignment_id and task_type_id = 1;
            end if;
```

Comment: What are you talking about?  Your description is not at all clear. What does not working mean? Do you get an error, if so what is it. Does it just not produce the correct results, if so what is produces and what is expected. Please review [ask] and re-post you question following its suggestions.

Comment: edited my question